# Не работает меню с case в С

Tags: c, меню, case

В программе на вход подается номер меню, где можно выбрать несколько пунктов: создать массив, вывести его, применить к нему сортировку (отдельно она работает), вывести отсортированный массив.

Однако при выборе пункта меню программа ничего не выдает, фактически не создается изначальный массив, все перепробовала, но никак не получается устранить ошибку.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "locale.h"
#define nmax 200

int item(char menu[][60], int nmenu){   //выбор пункта меню
    int i,k;
    for(i=0; i<nmenu; i++){
        printf("%s", menu[i]);
    }
    scanf("%d", &k);
    return k;
}

void sortbubble(int x[], int nx){  //сортировка
    int i, j, c;
    for(i=0; i<nx-1-i; i++){
        for(j=0; j<nx-1-j; j++){
            if(x[j]>x[j+1]){
                c=x[j];
                x[j]=x[j+1];
                x[j+1]=c;
            }
        }
    }
}



void printar(int x[], int nx){    //печать массива
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<nx; k++);
      printf("%d ", x[k]);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){ //основная программа
    int i;
    int k;
    int st, fn;
    int a[nmax], bb[nmax];
    double t0=0;
    int pr=0; 
    int pr2=0;
    char m[4][60]={"0 - Ввод\n","1 - печать исходного массива\n","2 - Сортировка пузырьком\n","3 - Вывод массива\n"};
    int nm=4; 
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    do{
        k=item(m, nm);
        switch(k){
           case 0: 
       {
         for(i=0; i<nmax; i++)
            a[i]=rand();
         pr=1; 
       }  
           case 1:
       {
         printar(a,nmax);
       }
           case 2:
       {
         if (pr==1){  //проверка, введен ли массив
           for (i=0; i<nmax; i++)
              bb[i]=a[i];
         }
         else 
         {
          for(i=0; i<nmax; i++){
               a[i]=rand();
               bb[i]=a[i];
          }
          pr=1;
         }

         pr2=1;

         st=clock();
         sortbubble(bb, nmax);
         fn=clock();

         t0=(fn-st)/2;
         t0/=1000.0;

         printf("\nВремя выполнения сортировки пузырьком %lf \n", t0);
         break;


    }      
           case 3: 
       {
         if(pr2==1){
           printf("\nОтсортированный массив ");
           printf("\n");
           printar(ch, nmax);
         }
         else
           printf("\nВыберете сортировку массива");
       }     
        }
    }
        while(k<5);
getchar();
}
```

Comment: в `printar` в цикле `for` есть лишняя точка с запятой

Comment: После каждого case надо ставить ключевое слово break. Почему так надо подробно описывают в учебниках.

Comment: http://easy-code.ru/lesson/switch-case-cpp

Comment: @OlegUP, почему после каждого?

Comment: @eanmos Вы тоже новичок? Потому что если не поставить break, то отработают все остальные case'ы. По ссылке выше об этом написано.

Comment: @OlegUP, нет, почему именно после каждого? Что если мне нужен fall-through?

Comment: @eanmos Задавшему вопрос он не нужен.

Comment: @OlegUP, мне почему-то показалось, что вы имеете в виду, что `break` нужно абсолютно во всех случаях ставить.